# Bootstrap-Select Does not shows ticks next to selected options(Multiple)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-select

I have an issue with selector where I am defining as:

```
 <select name='provs[]' id="prov" class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" required multiple>
```

However, When I am selecting the data, it doesn't show me the ticks next to the options.
I am using bootstrap 2.3.2 with bootstrap-select. I have the css and js of them added to my asserts. I can choose and get the values however, I am not able to see the ticks next to the options when I am selecting them.

Cheers,

Answer (score 8):

It's always wise to look through the scripts you are using even if they don't mean much, they will make sense after awhile.

Reference: https://github.com/caseyjhol/bootstrap-select/blob/master/bootstrap-select.js

See lines 942-965 and locate near the bottom:

```
$.fn.selectpicker.defaults = {
.... // bunch of default settings
iconBase: 'glyphicon', // the font family for the checkmark
tickIcon: 'glyphicon-ok', // classname for the checkmark
...
};
```

This defaults to glyphicon, part of Bootstrap 3. You will need to install this font or you can use Font Awesome (go to their site, follow instructions) and change the two values when you call the script:

```
 $('.selectpicker').selectpicker({
   iconBase: 'NameofFOnt',
   tickIcon: 'classname'
});
```

Comment: However, I have been using Bootstrap 2.3.2 for almost a year and this function was working before. Suddenly those ticks disappeared.

Comment: On the same site? Same version of the plugin?

Comment: Try changing the class on the select to class="selectpicker show-tick" (vs. "selectpicker")

Comment: It doesn't help as well. Nothing changes when i add show-tick.

Comment: For Font-Awesome, use iconBase as 'fontawesome' and tickIcon as 'fa fa-check'.

Answer (score 7):

This "problem" still exists within Bootstrap 4 as Bootstrap-select uses Glyphicon. Putting together all the answers this helped me (BS4.3.1, fa 5.7.1, BS-select 1.13.8):

```
<select data-icon-base="fas" data-tick-icon="fa-check">
```

Use the snake case as mentioned [here](https://github.com/snapappointments/bootstrap-select/issues/1860)

Comment: When used with Bootstrap 4, bootstrap-select v1.13.0+ uses a pure CSS solution to create the tick icon (instead of Glyphicon).

Answer (score 2):

add Font Awesome css in your HTML page.

```
 <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

and replace these in  `bootstrap-select.js` and `bootstrap-select.min.js`

```
iconBase: 'glyphicon', tickIcon: 'glyphicon-ok'
```

to

```
iconBase:"fontawesome",tickIcon:"fa fa-check"
```

Comment: Not helpful if you're using the scripts from a CDN. Plus it's not recommended to change the files anyway.

Answer (score 0):

**If you are talking about way through CDN so, this is the solution:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.10.0/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.10.0/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="http://cdn.rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="http://cdn.rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css"rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $('#lstFruits').multiselect({
                includeSelectAllOption: true
            });
            $('#btnSelected').click(function () {
                var selected = $("#lstFruits option:selected");
                var message = "";
                selected.each(function () {
                    message += $(this).text() + " " + $(this).val() + "\n";
                });
            });
        });
    </script>

    <style>


    </style>



</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="box">
                <div class="box-body">
                    <form action="#" method="POST">
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <select class="form-control selectpicker" id="select-country lstFruits" multiple="multiple" data-live-search="true" >
                                    <option data-tokens="china">China</option>
                                    <option data-tokens="malayasia">Malayasia</option>
                                    <option data-tokens="singapore">Singapore</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and if you want to add the icons offline files so you can import the icons through import, just place the below code above your bootstrap css.

```
 @import url("//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css");
```